# Backbone Mobile Events

Tags: javascript, mobile, backbone.js, zepto

Are there any good resources which events to use on mobile phones, I tried all these 3 events they all seem to have different pros and cons. 'Click' doesnt feel as natural as 'touchend'. However 'touchend' is very very sensitive. As I try to scroll down I accidentally 'touch' to links. How do I solve this issue? Should I just use click, whats the best practice?

Maybe "Tap" is the answer to the question above but 'tap' doesnt seem to work. Where can I find a complete list of all the events that can be fired? Does this depend on backbone itself or the second library that I am using (jquery or zepto)

```
var EmailView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events:{

           "tap .delete-fooditem" : "edit",
                    // "click .delete-fooditem" : "edit",
                    // "touchend .delete-fooditem" : "edit",

            },

    edit : function(e){
            console.log("edit")
    },
)};
```

Comment: backbone is wrapping jquery/zepto's event handling, so you'll need to understand that dependency

Comment: "Uses jQuery's on function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view." this is what the documentation says.. So does that mean that it replaces Jquery with zepto when I am using zepto?

Comment: yes, the documentation should be more explicit about that, but that's what happens